# Hibernate get() method vs hql. which would be best approach?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to understand the best solution for the following use case. Any inputs would be really helpful.

Consider the following scenario:
A,B,C,D are four tables, with One to many mapping between them.

```
A --> B --> C --> D
A (One) --> B (Many) and so on..
```

My use case is, I need to get the data from table A based on a column value in **D which is not a primary key**.

As per my understanding (Still new to Hibernate, so please correct me if i am wrong :)), there are 2 approach

**Approach 1:** Using the get() method
First get the primary key value using the hibernate Query and then call the get method

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from D where ...");

Int id = query.list().get(0).getId();
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(id);
```

**Approach 2:** Use hibernate query and joins
Create a string by joining all the 4 tables and pass to the create query method.

```
Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(sql);
```

I want to know:

> 1. Is there a way to call get method by passing non primary key column value
> 2. apart from these approach is there any other approach?
> 3. which is better approach

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dedicated query returning the wanted data directly will of course be more efficient that executing a query to find D, and then getting C from D, B from C and finally A from B. Especially if the associations are lazy.

Efficiency is not the only thing that matters, though. But since you need to write a query to get D anyway, I would write the query to get the wanted information instead.

Just a note on your first strategy:

```
int id = query.list().get(0).getId();
D d = (D) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(id);
```

The second line is completely useless. It will return the entity that was already found by the query. All you need is

```
D d = (D) query.list().get(0);
```

or better, since the query should return a single entity

```
D d = (D) query.uniqueResult();
```

Also, what you pass to createQuery() is not SQL. It's HQL. Those are different languages.

Comment: Thanks for the response and clarification